# Seleccionar los nombres de los empleados que no son administradores

Tags: sql

Estoy tratando de realizar un query basado en la jerarquía de empleados de una organización.

Un empleado es un administrador si cualquier otro empleado tiene su managerId establecido al primer id de empleados. Un empleado que es un administrador puede o no puede ser un administrador también.

```
TABLE employees
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  managerId INTEGER REFERENCES employees(id)
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL

-- Example case create statement:
CREATE TABLE employees (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  managerId INTEGER REFERENCES employees(id), 
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO employees(id, managerId, name) VALUES(1, NULL, 'John');
INSERT INTO employees(id, managerId, name) VALUES(2, 1, 'Mike');

-- Salida esperada
-- name
-- ----
-- Mike

-- Explicación:
-- En este ejemplo.
-- John es el administrador de Mike. Mike no administra a nadie.
-- Mike es el único empleado que no administra a nadie.
```

¿Cómo puedo realizar la query? He tratado de realizar varios queries pero ninguno me da el resultado deseado por que no logro plasmar la idea muy bien en mi cabeza.

El ejercicio es sacado de [aquí](https://www.testdome.com/questions/sql/workers/13066?questionIds=11100,10944,7278,13066&generatorId=32&type=fromtest&testDifficulty=Hard).

Comment: Hola Hoose. Aunque tus consultas no hayan resultado, se aprecia que inluyas estos intentos en tu pregunta para que quede claro que sí hubo esfuerzo de tu parte en resolver tu duda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece que simplemente debes encontrar los ids de empleados que no existen como `managerId` en la misma tabla. Por lo que esta consulta parece ser suficiente:

```
SELECT name
FROM employees e
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM employees
                 WHERE managerId = e.Id);
```